# Azure Firewall Limitation - Updating Rules

Tags: azure

I'm trying to get the company to use Azure Firewall as we start to move production workloads to Azure, however the network team have stated there are limitations when using Azure firewall. For example they have saod the Firewall reboots or drops all connections when you update a rule on it?

Is this true? Would anyone know of any limitations of using Azure Firewall. The network team prefer to use Checkpoint firewalls in Azure which are fine, but I would rather use Azure firewall, if its not going to fall down eveytime we do an update to teh rules.

That just doesn't sound like its right, as Azure Firewall is prouction ready resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

•   Please find the link below for detailed known documented limitations of Azure Firewall: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/overview#known-issues

It clearly states all the issues regarding configuration of rules, NAT of UDR and other features of Azure that are used in integration with it. There, it clearly states that for configuration updates regarding the Azure Firewall, it takes three (3) to five (5) minutes on average to take effect independently, i.e., if multiple configuration updates are done to the Azure Firewall, each configuration update takes separate time to take effect and reciprocate it in its functioning. Thus, please check this, and as for updating of rules is concerned, I don’t think the existing rules defined on Azure Firewall are dysfunctional or the Azure Firewall as an appliance goes down for few periods of time when the rules are getting updated.

Comment: Hi @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT, Do we put Azure Firewall in front of the Application gateway or behind the Azure Application Gateway?

Comment: Hi @SeniorSystemsEngineer, we put the Azure Firewall in front of the Application Gateway as it is an OSI Layer 4 device and application gateway behind it as it works on an OSI Layer 7 due to which Azure Firewall works on routing and filtering the traffic received on a transport level while application gateway works on the inherent message and information passed through it.

Comment: Hi @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT, OK, so in this case, would it be possible to deploy the Azure Firewall in front of the StorageAccount or the App Service (PaaS)?